# Use a swift file for data storage?

Tags: ios, storage, swift4, xcode9, filesize

I'm new to coding and building my first app. I have some static data - read only, not varying, that I need to store. It is a nested dictionary with about 150 String keys and 2000 arrays, each array has 10 integers. The user selects 3 keys from a picker and it returns the 10 integers from 1 array. Can I just copy it into a swift file (like Apple do in their 'App Development' book). I have looked around but most of the answers are quite old, so not sure if they are good for Swift 4/x code 9, also most answers use terms like 'large' or 'small' amounts of data, where does 20,000 integers fit?

Comment: Use a Property List